# MATLAB gradient descent oddly faster without feature normalizing

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm implementing simple multivariate linear regression in MATLAB. My implementation includes feature normalization of the data, which is essentially: for feature `x(i)`, set `x(i) = (x(i) - μ)/σ`, where *μ* and *σ* are the average and range, respectively, of each feature's values.

I benchmarked my code's runtime, and it seems that whenever I **don't** apply feature normalization, performance is much faster. (I tried this with several different training data sets.)
Since normalization is meant to speed up the code, I'd appreciate any help that would point out what's wrong with my implementation.

```
function [Theta, cost] = linearRegression(Trainset, max_cost)
% LINEAR REGRESSION - Given trainset and desired maximum cost for linear
% model, use gradient descent to return optimized Theta and its cost.

%% INITIALIZATION
m = size(Trainset,1); n = size(Trainset,2)-1;
X = [ones(m,1), Trainset(:,1:n)]; % X = <Mx(N+1)>
Y = Trainset(:,n+1); % Y = <Mx1>
Theta = zeros(1, n+1); % Theta = <1x(N+1)>
alpha = optimizeAlpha(X, Y);

%% FEATURE NORMALIZATION
avg = mean(X(:,2:n+1)); rng = range(X(:,2:n+1));
X(:,2:n+1) = (X(:,2:n+1) - repmat(avg, [m,1]))./(repmat(rng, [m,1]));

%% METHODS
% J - Cost function (sum of squared errors)
% GD - A single step in gradient descent
J=@(X, Y, Theta) (1/2/m)*sum((X*Theta' - Y).^2);
GD=@(X, Y, Theta, alpha) Theta - (alpha/m)*(X*Theta' - Y)'*X;

%% APPLY GRADIENT DESCENT UNTIL CONVERGENCE
while (J(X, Y, Theta) > max_cost),
    Theta = GD(X, Y, Theta, alpha);
end

cost = J(X, Y, Theta);
end
```

(Side note: `optimizeAlpha` is a helper method I wrote to pick a relatively large learning rate alpha, which is still sufficiently small to ensure gradient descent will converge. If you think it's of relevance to my problem, I'll include the code for this method too.)

Many thanks!

Comment: How many times is the while loop running in each case? My best guess is that by normalizing the inputs you are inadvertently scaling the error value which would mean that different cost values would have the same performance in each case.